# Using Google Coud Run (or any cloud service) with Docker-compose app with simple python script

Tags: google-cloud-platform, docker-compose, google-cloud-run

I have a relatively simple docker application using docker-compose that I would like to deploy. All it contains is a python script that I would like to automatically run every day that doesn't require user input.

I would like to use Google Cloud Run to deploy this application, since it doesn't need to be online 24/7. but I'm not sure if it's compatible with a docker-compose.yml.

Here is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.9'

secrets:
  venmo_api_key:
    file: ./secrets/venmo_api_token.txt

services:
  app:
    build: ./app
    secrets:
      - venmo_api_key
```

As you can see, I need docker-compose so that my secrets can be used in my container just by running `docker-compose up`. It runs fine locally!

To deploy to my image to Google Container Registry, I've run:

1. `docker-compose build`
2. `docker tag cb3605 gcr.io/venmoscription-v2/venmoscription-service`
3. `docker push gcr.io/venmoscription-v2/venmoscription-service`

In Google Cloud Run, I selected the GCR URL and left all the other options as default just to see if my container could run online. However, I got this error in Google Cloud Run Logs:

```
False for Revision venmoscription-service-00001-qig with message: Cloud Run error: Container failed to start. Failed to start and then listen on the port defined by the PORT environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information.
```

I also got this error message after:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/main.py", line 13, in <module>
    client = Client(access_token = get_docker_secret("venmo_api_key"))
  File "/home/app/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/venmo_api/venmo.py", line 15, in __init__
    self.__profile = self.user.get_my_profile()
  File "/home/app/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/venmo_api/apis/user_api.py", line 26, in get_my_profile
    response = self.__api_client.call_api(resource_path=resource_path,
  File "/home/app/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/venmo_api/utils/api_client.py", line 58, in call_api
    return self.__call_api(resource_path=resource_path, method=method,
  File "/home/app/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/venmo_api/utils/api_client.py", line 103, in __call_api
    processed_response = self.request(method, url, session,
  File "/home/app/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/venmo_api/utils/api_client.py", line 139, in request
    validated_response = self.__validate_response(response, ok_error_codes=ok_error_codes)
  File "/home/app/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/venmo_api/utils/api_client.py", line 170, in __validate_response
    raise HttpCodeError(response=response)
venmo_api.models.exception.HttpCodeError: HTTP Status code is invalid. Could not make the request because -> 401 Unauthorized.
```

Basically, the container in Google Cloud Run was unable to access the secret that I defined in docker-compose.yml.

Does anyone know what I should be doing, or please explain how to get my docker-compose app up and running with a serverless solution? Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Run doesn't support multiple containers like docker-compose does, so you'll need to deploy a single container that accomplishes your goal. Cloud Run does expect that your container starts up and listens on a port (like a web application) or else it won't start.

This page has a good step by step simple python app that can deploy on Cloud Run and listens on a port
https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy/python

You can also make your venmo secret available at a path for your service by using Google Secret Manager.
https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/secrets

I hope that helps get you started.

Best,
Josh

Comment: Hey Josh, thanks for the answer. So you're saying that even though my docker-compose is only for one container, because docker-compose can support multiple containers, Cloud Run doesn't let you use them. This means I'll probably have to build my image and feed secrets into it through command-line arguments instead of using docker-compose. Additionally, the container that I want to deploy doesn't need to listen to a port to run, but I'll need it to listen to a port regardless?